# Handle o:p tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I was extracting some disease information from : http://people.dbmi.columbia.edu/~friedma/Projects/DiseaseSymptomKB/index.html

but the data was contained inside a  tag which I don't know how to handle.

One way I found was using find_all function but is there any way to do it as tr.td.span.[o:p or something]  ??

```
<td width="584" nowrap="" valign="top" style="width:438.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
  height:12.75pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">UMLS:C0008031_pain
  chest
<o:p>&nsp</o:p>
</span>
</p>
  </td>
```

Comment: i try to understand what you want to extract and what the issue is but I'm unable to reach the point yet

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I need to know what's inside the o:p tag

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "http://people.dbmi.columbia.edu/~friedma/Projects/DiseaseSymptomKB/index.html")[0]

df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/dd4d958d4c31a34cb624879700060310/out.csv)

that's in case if you want full table.

but for your requirement.

Use:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "http://people.dbmi.columbia.edu/~friedma/Projects/DiseaseSymptomKB/index.html")[0]

print(df[2][1:].values.tolist())
```

For `bs4`

use

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "http://people.dbmi.columbia.edu/~friedma/Projects/DiseaseSymptomKB/index.html")


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("p", {'class': 'MsoNormal'}):
    item = item.get_text(strip=True)
    if item.startswith("UMLS"):
        print(item)
```