# Make json file from html table

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, converters

Here is an Html table in this website http://people.dbmi.columbia.edu/~friedma/Projects/DiseaseSymptomKB/

There is a column named "Disease Name" and the following column named "Symptoms". I want JSON formatted data from that table of that website like this manner and also remove the "UMLS:C00080" thing from the strings.

```
data = {
   {
    disease_name:'name',
    symptoms: [symptoms ]
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do it with python?

Comment: Look up some examples of web scraping with requests and beautifulsoup4

Comment: Couldn't find relative examples

Comment: https://github.com/anujdutt9/Disease-Prediction-from-Symptoms/blob/master/Disease-Prediction-from-Symptoms.ipynb

Comment: Here is the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59660402/9032909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With BS4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "http://people.dbmi.columbia.edu/~friedma/Projects/DiseaseSymptomKB/index.html")


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("p", {'class': 'MsoNormal'}):
    item = item.get_text(strip=True)
    if item.startswith("UMLS"):
        print(item)
```